# Array of Struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I want to just hard code these values into a table. when I try to use 2D arrays, I run into the problem of dealing with characters and integers. When I do a struct I have this so far but it doesn't divide the information up in columns, and I'm not sure how to format it that way. (I only did 3 rows to start off with, if I get them working, the rest will just be the same)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

typedef struct table
{
    std::string game;
    int year;
    float rating;
    int num_voters;
}t;

void processTab(t*);
int main()
{
t tabl[2] = {0,0};
int i;
processTab(tabl);
for(i=0; i<2; i++)
{
         std::cout << "Game: " << setw(20) << tabl[i].game;
         std::cout << "\tYear: " << setw(4) << tabl[i].year;
         std::cout << "\tRating: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << tabl[i].rating;
         std::cout << "\tVoters: " << setw(6) << tabl[i].num_voters;
 }

system("pause");
return 0;
}
void processTab(t*tab)
{
 (tab[0].game, "twilight struggles");
 tab[0].year = 2005;
 tab[0].rating = 8.226;
 tab[0].num_voters = 10690;

 (tab[1].game, "Agricloa");
 tab[1].year = 2007;
 tab[1].rating = 8.17;
 tab[1].num_voters = 23738;

(tab[2].game, "Puerto Rico");
 tab[2].year = 2002;
 tab[2].rating = 8.163;
 tab[2].num_voters = 27433;

 }

Table Data:
Game (0)            Year (1)  Rating (2)  Num Voters (3)
Twilight Struggle   2005      8.226       10690
Agricola            2007      8.17        23738
Puerto Rico         2002      8.163       27433
Through the Ages    2006      8.153       8137
Power Grid          2004      8.02        21655
Le Havre            2008      7.972       9258
Eclipse             2011      7.968       3194
Brass               2007      7.911       5814
Dominion: Intrigue  2009      7.895       10889
Caylus              2005      7.878       13878
```

Comment: What is your question? (also your struct looks like C code, in C++, you just write `struct table{};`)

Comment: Possible error: your datatype of t.game is char and you are trying to copy strings to it. Possible error2: using strcpy!

Comment: You should use `std::string` instead of `char` for `game`, unless `game` is always a single character. Also, your `strcpy` lines should not compile, but then you wouldn't use them if you used `std::string` (you just use the `=` operator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is [`<iomanip>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/)

```
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << "Game: " << setw(20) << tabl[i].game;
std::cout << "\tYear: " << setw(4) << tabl[i].year;
std::cout << "\tRating: " << fixed << setprecision(3) << tabl[i].rating;
std::cout << "\tVoters: " << setw(6) << tabl[i].num_voters;
std::cout << std::end;
```

Notes:
[`setw`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/) adds padding when writing out stuff, so it will always be at least a certain width
[`setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/)  specifies how many decimal places to display
[`fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/) makes floating point *never* use scientific notation

Your `game` member is a letter, and you're attemptying to assign it a string.  Don't use `strcpy` in C++, use the `std::string` class instead.

```
#include <string>
struct table
{
    std::string game;
    int year;
    double rating;
    int num_voters;
};
```

Avoid `using namespace std;`, when you get to complex code with many namespaces, those few letters are a small price to pay for avoiding confusion.
Avoid `endl`: it flushes buffers which is slow.  If you just want a newline, use `'\n'`.
Also, you can use the new initialization syntax to initialize your list:

```
std::vector<table> tbal = { 
                 {"twilight struggles  ", 2005, 8.226, 10690},
                 {"Agricola            ", 2007, 8.17 , 23738},
                 {"Puerto Rico         ", 2002, 8.163, 27433}
               };
```

Comment: Would this be the function definition(after the main)?

Comment: The advice to avoid `using namespace std;` is ungood. One must apply intelligence to everything. There are contexts where it's bad, and contexts where it's good, and a beginner is only visiting the latter category of contexts. But more importantly, should not be taught to use mechanical rules. Should be taught to think. Secondly, the advice to consider the efficiency of `endl` is bad. For efficiency, don't use iostreams. Also, don't fret the small stuff. Beginners should not be taught to think of micro-efficiency. It's the most common cause of beginner's spaghetti.

Comment: -1 for the "If you have a newer compiler", which is ungood. This initialization of an aggregate has been supported since the ARM (before C++98).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I mention that because it hasn't worked for `std::string` until recently.  If the member is a `const char*` or `char[]`, then you're right that it worked before this year.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: `std::vector` isn't an aggregate, and couldn't be initialised with that syntax before C++11.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: good eye on the 'double', I'd overlooked that.  Since I was suggesting replacing the 'game' with a string, C++03 would _not_ have allowed the initialization.  As per your "suggestion", I added a note that similar initialization was possible in C++03.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: C++03 allows such initialization even when the struct contains a `std::string`. It's then an aggregate, not a POD. Curly braces initialization has been allowed for aggregates since C++98 and before. The only new thing in C++03, namely value initialization, was suggested by Andrew Koenig in order to make the rules for initialization of aggregates have the same conceptual effect as the rules for plain PODs. That is, to avoid surprising and hence bug-inducing cases where initialization was not performed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: [huh, I stand corrected](http://ideone.com/g4Bz7).  `ThingsKnown += 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: use `std::vector`, not a raw array.

The following is as close to your original code as I could make it, introducing a minimum number of new features for you:

```
#include <assert.h>         // assert
#include <iostream>         // std::cout, std::endl
#include <stddef.h>         // ptrdiff_t
#include <string>           // std::string
#include <utility>          // std::begin, std::end
#include <vector>           // std::vector
using namespace std;

typedef ptrdiff_t       Size;

template< class Container >
Size countOf( Container& c ) { return end( c ) - begin( c ); }

struct Game
{
    string  game;
    int     year;
    double  rating;
    int     num_voters;
};

void initialize( vector<Game>& games )
{
    assert( countOf( games ) == 0 );
    games.resize( 3 );

    games[0].game = "twilight struggles";
    games[0].year = 2005;
    games[0].rating = 8.226;
    games[0].num_voters = 10690;

    games[1].game = "Agricloa";
    games[1].year = 2007;
    games[1].rating = 8.17;
    games[1].num_voters = 23738;

    games[2].game = "Puerto Rico";
    games[2].year = 2002;
    games[2].rating = 8.163;
    games[2].num_voters = 27433;
}

int main()
{
    vector<Game> games;

    initialize( games );
    for( int i = 0; i < countOf( games ); ++i )
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        cout <<"\tGame: " << games[i].game << endl;
        cout<<"\tYear: " << games[i].year << endl;
        cout<<"\trating: " << games[i].rating << endl;
        cout<<"\tnum voters: " << games[i].num_voters << endl;
    }
}
```

There are ways to just declare the data more directly, including brace initializers; check out your C++ textbook.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define your `table` (bad name for a `struct`, by the way) correctly. You're trying to use `game` to store a string, but have defined it as only a single `char`. You probably want to change that to a `std::string` instead.

Then you probably want to do your formatting in an `operator<<` overloaded to take a reference to `table` as the type. @MooingDuck has already covered the formatting itself quite well, so it's mostly a matter of how you package that:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, table const &t) { 
    os << "Game: " << setw(20) << t.game;
    os << "\tYear: " << setw(4) << t.year;
    os << "\tRating: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << t.rating;
    return os << "\tVoters: " << setw(6) << t.num_voters;    
}
```

Along with that, you almost certainly want to change `tabl` from an array to `std::vector<table>`:

```
std::vector<tabl> tabl;
```

Then processing the table becomes:

```
std::copy(tabl.begin(), tabl.end(), std::ostream_iterator<table>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

One other minor detail: you seem to have two entirely different/separate functions, both named `processTab`. You probably want to rename at least one of those. Just glancing at them, I'd probably call one `initializeTable` or something on that order.